# Form Not Found When Attempting to Fill Using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I'm learning CasperJS and want to try a simple, somewhat useful task.  I'd like to make a pdf copy of my gas bill, but I can't even log into the website.

I'm a customer of CT Natural Gas.  The URL is:

https://www.cngcorp.com/wps/portal/cng/home/mycng/customerWebAccess/

Logging in should be simple.  It should just be my account number and last name.

My code is:

```
var start_url = "https://www.cngcorp.com/wps/portal/cng/home/mycng/customerWebAccess/"
var casper = require('casper').create()

casper.start(start_url, function() {

    this.fill('formid', {
        'input1id': '000000000000',
        'input2id': 'LastName'
    }, true);
    this.capture('cng.png');

})
casper.run()
```

My "real" code uses the full ID shown in the site's HTML, not "formid" or "input1ID".  I did not include the full ID in the sample code above because I was unsure what those ID's really were.  They look something like: viewns_7_LOIGMC7IA21234QWERASDF1234_:custWebLogin.  So much for a "simple" ID.  Maybe this is something generated from a WebSphere product?

Anyway, the form is not found.  I get:

```
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
```

I've also hacked it a bit and put this in my `start` to see what the form "looks like":

```
listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
        return node.id;
    })
})

this.echo(listItems);
```

That returns:

```
,viewns_7_LOIGMC7IA21234QWERASDF1234_:custWebLogin
```

I think the form id is messing this up.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the form to be loaded to fill the form using the selectors.Use have waitForSelector(),waitFor(),wait() etc other than waitForResource()

```
casper.start('your_url_here',function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.waitForResource("your_url_here",function() {
    this.fillSelectors('#loginform', {
        'input[name="Email"]' : 'your_email',
        'input[name="Passwd"]': 'your_password'
    }, true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the DOM/CSS3 Selectores doesn't work with this ID but it works with xpath :

```
// Create a function for selectXPath : 
var x = require('casper').selectXPath

var start_url = "https://www.cngcorp.com/wps/portal/cng/home/mycng/customerWebAccess/"
var casper = require('casper').create()

casper.start(start_url, function() {
    // Query xpath with fillSelectors
    this.fill(x('//*[@id="viewns_7_LOIGMC7IA26I00I9TQ9SLI1B12_:custWebLogin"]'), {
        'input1id': '000000000000',
        'input2id': 'LastName'
    }, true);
    this.capture('cng.png');

})
casper.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the full ID? Because maybe something like that could work :

```
this.fill("form[id^='viewns_7_LOIGMC7IA21234QWERASDF1234']", {
    'input1id': '000000000000',
    'input2id': 'LastName'
```

Or

```
this.fill("form[id*='LOIGMC7IA21234QWERASDF1234']", {
    'input1id': '000000000000',
    'input2id': 'LastName'
```